# Control push segue button in master/detail template in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, master-detail

Using the master/detail template you get an automatic push segue between master and detail views.  How do I access the logic of the returning button (as shown on the left of the upper bar in the detail view)?    Before I let the user return to the master, I want to apply some checks regarding the work they did while in the detail view.  There must be a method for this button that I can somehow override??  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of days after posting here, I posted the same question on Apple's developer forum
https://developer.apple.com/devforums/
and received a terrific solution.  Below is a link to that solution by MVC123.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/910072#910072

Answer (score 1):

You can catch them if you use

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    //This is called when the user has clicked on the back button in the navigation bar.
}
```

method...

I hope it helps...

Comment: I tried this:-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    //This is called when the user has clicked on the back button in the navigation bar.
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    NSLog(@"\n\nviewWillDisappear called");
    return ;
}   to no avail.   The master view just clicked in as usual and continued.  I thought the return might stop it  From what I can find out about viewwillDisappear, it is too late to use it.

Comment: If you have any codes in the prepareForSegue method of your child view, can you please try again after commenting them?

Comment: The prepareForSegue code is all in the Master view, not the Detail view.